# embedded jetty war deploy logs for logback

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm using a embedded jetty in my application and I have configured a war deployed folder as follow.

```
        // === jetty-deploy.xml ===

        DeploymentManager deployer = new DeploymentManager();
        deployer.setContexts(contexts);
        deployer.setContextAttribute(
                "org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",
                ".*/servlet-api-[^/]*\\.jar$");

        WebAppProvider webapp_provider = new WebAppProvider();
        webapp_provider.setMonitoredDirName("jetty_base/webapps");
        //webapp_provider.setDefaultsDescriptor("jetty_base/webapps/webdefault.xml");
        webapp_provider.setScanInterval(1);
        webapp_provider.setExtractWars(true);
        webapp_provider.setConfigurationManager(new PropertiesConfigurationManager());

        deployer.addAppProvider(webapp_provider);
        server.addBean(deployer);


        org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog());
        //Log.setLog(new Slf4jLog());
```

When I deploy my war file using standard jetty distribution (jetty-distribution-9.3.6.v20151106) I can get logs in my *.stderrout.log files.

But problem I face is I can't get logs when I use my above embedded jetty.
I tried both StdErrLog and Slf4jLog for Log.setLog

In my war file there are logs with logback. Following line is extracted from log file of standard distribution

```
 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The creation of `*.stderrlog.log` files is an artifact of how jetty-distribution behaves, its not appropriate for [embedded-jetty](/questions/tagged/embedded-jetty), don't try to accomplish that end-goal.

As for configuring logging, that needs to happen early, as in VERY early, as early as you can possibly make it happen.  If you can make it happen before you instantiate anything in Jetty that would be ideal.

Some options to try *(only try 1 of the following, not a combination of them)*:

### 1) Let Jetty Logging Auto-Configure

By default, the existence of `slf4j-api.jar` in your classpath will cause jetty to auto-configure for slf4j (which in yourcase will use logback as its implementation)

Don't call `Log.setLog()` anywhere, let jetty do its thing.

### 2) Specify the `Log.setLog()` early

Try simply putting this static block in your main class.

```java
static {
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.setLog(new Slf4jLog());
}
```

Don't call `Log.setLog()` anywhere else.

### 3) Add a `jetty-logging.properties` to your classpath

Create a `jetty-logging.properties` file somewhere where it will be in your classpath (the root of your jar file is a good place), add the following line:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
```